# Dealing with Webpack outside of the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I love a lot about Webpack and there’s no shortage of blog posts singing its praises so I’ll just reiterate that what it does is incredible for generating a client side js bundle along with ancillary files like css, images, markdown, etc. Now on to the problems…

Using `require` for non-js files has been a major hassle to get around outside of the browser-bundle context. I’ll just talk about two big ones I’ve faced.

1. Rendering react components server-side that `require` non-js files.
2. Running integration tests on express middleware that `require` files that in-turn `require` other non-js files. The middleware itself is fine.

I’ve gotten around the first issue using [Webpack Isomorphic Tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools) which seems like an ok workaround. I was doing a second server side Webpack bundle but I didn't like the dev-server/rebuild setup I had. I’m still not sure how best to handle the mocha issue. Tests I have that run in a browser are fine using Karma and karma-webpack. But I want my middleware test to run on Node.

Once I decided to require a non-js file I really tied my hands on how I can work with that file. I’m really curious what others are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried crafting a setup with both server side and client side Webpack builds.
https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-react-redux-isomorphic-render-example
Seems to work ok, still it may be not the best solution.